# Blending several fragment shaders in THREE.js to obtain one THREE.ShaderMaterial

Tags: three.js, fragment-shader, alphablending

I have a question about blending several fragment shaders in THREE.js
Here I present a code for mixing one shader with different parameters, but I also need to mix different shaders.

My shader:

```
uniform vec3 color;
  varying vec2 vUv;
  void main() {
    gl_FragColor = vec4(color,vUv.y);

  }
```

Then i define uniforms and materials:

```
var uniforms1 = {
    "color" : {
        type : "c",
        value : new THREE.Color(0x00ff00)
    },
};
var uniforms2 = {
    "color" : {
        type : "c",
        value : new THREE.Color(0xff0000)
    },
};

var material1 = new THREE.ShaderMaterial({
    uniforms: uniforms1,
    vertexShader: vShader,
    fragmentShader: fShader,
    transparent: true
});
var material2 = new THREE.ShaderMaterial({
    uniforms: uniforms2,
    vertexShader: vShader,
    fragmentShader: fShader,
    transparent: true
});
```

Till now everything looks ok. But then I want to overlay them and do it in a strange way creating two objects:

```
var geometry = new THREE.CircleGeometry(50, 50);
mesh1 = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material1);
mesh2 = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material2);
mesh1.rotation.z = -0.25 * Math.PI;
mesh2.rotation.z = 0.25 * Math.PI;
```

Thus I have a result I need, but I understand, that it is not a good idea to create separate mesh for each shader. Moreover, if my object will not be symmetric I will have troubles. 
**Is it possible to blend shaders and obtain one material?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can blend shaders using [EffectComposer](https://github.com/hughsk/three-effectcomposer), however here it seems rather straightforward to directly blend the color in a single shader new `THREE.Color(0xffff00)` if that's the result you are looking for, but you may be looking for something more complex ...

Comment: 1) THREE.Color(0xffff00) will not work, as I rotate gradients to +/-pi/4. 2) You are right I plan to make some more complex stuff, 3) will effectcompose work without install, I mean if i wish to see it on some third-part PC without any preinstallations? Thanks

Comment: We are talking browser app here, so there is no third party plugin to install, only a browser that is WebGL compatible. However I'm not sure you will be able to obtain the same effect than what you have now by applying a composed effect to your meshes, you should rather implement a more complex unique shader or keep going with your current approach unless it becomes a major performance issue.

Comment: "We are talking browser app here" just first what I've read in composer page : `npm install three-effectcomposer` and I was afraid, that it will not work in pure WebGL browser. Thanks.

Comment: This package is designed to use the EffectComposer plugin with bundler such as Browserify/Webpack Typically you download npm dependencies and use those to generate a bundle that contain code of your web app, there is no need to install anything locally on the client machines once your web app has been deployed. You should be able to use EffectComposer without this package, simply by adding the extra files to your html if you are not using a build step. Here "plugin" means an extra lib that adds features to Three.js, it is not a binary that needs to be installed on all the clients.